# Why does Powershell always run as Admin now?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, administrator

I'm running Windows 7, and recently installed the update so I can use Powershell 3.0. That process went fine and I've been using Powershell 3 for about a month now. One thing I noticed is that every time I run Powershell now, it runs with elevated privileges. I don't right click and Run As Administrator, I just do a normal left click. This happens when I run from the Start Menu, or when it's pinned to the task bar or however I start it. This never happened with Powershell 2. I've done nothing special to make it always run as Admin, as I don't want to always run as Admin. Does anyone have any suggestions of things I can check?

Comment: No, I have done nothing except run the update for Powershell 3.0.

Comment: @FactorMystic - What does disabling UAC have to do with running in admin mode?

Comment: I've also found disabling UAC causes PowerShell (and the normal cmd.exe) to run as Administrator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have set in the properties of the Powershell shorcut ( under Advanced ) and set it to run as Administrator, it will always run in admin mode. See if this is the case and remove the setting if so.

[image]

(Note that if the same shortcut is pinned, you will see the same effect when opening from pinned applications as well, as you experience)

Comment: If you are referring to the options in the Compatibility Mode tab, I have nothing checked off in there.

Comment: @campbell.rw - See the screenshot. Talking about the shortcut tab -> Advanced

Comment: Ah yes, I was looking at the wrong tab. That was my problem, thanks!